# Use AWS lambda to read Kinesis and save to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am very new to AWS. Upto now I am able to send csv data to kinesis streams using aws .net sdk. Now I have to save this data in S3 using lambda using S3 Emitter(this is the most common way which I found on many websites) . When I create a Lambda function for it. It asks for Node.js or java8 code. 
I don't understand from here , what code needs to be uploaded, how to use S3 Emitter code.
I cannot use Kinesis Firehose because the streaming data is going to EMR for processing.
Please help me here.
If there is any alternate way please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code that will get the events from the kinesis stream and write it to S3 (or even easier to Kinesis Firehose). This code should be in one of the programing languages that are supported in Lambda currently (JavaScript, Java, Python). 
Here is a tutorial for reading from Kinesis: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example.html

It is relatively easy to read the events and batch them to S3 or even easier to write them to Firehose to get a more optimized batches in S3 (larger, compressed, encrypted...).